# Special Relativity, Kinetics - Momentum and velocity

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity, kinematics, approximations

1. Suppose $ \bar{p} = \frac {v}{1-\frac 23 v^2}  $; show that $ \bar{p} =  {v}   { (1+\frac 23 v^2+･･･)\approx v }  $ when *v* is small.

Answer (score 1):

This is becaue the expansion of $\frac{1}{1-x}=1+x+x^2+...$ for x is near 0. If your $v$ is small, then plug in $x=\frac{2}{3}v^2$ to above and the conclusion follows.

Comment: And in general $(1+x)^v \approx 1+vx + \frac {v(v-1)} 2 x^2$ when $|a| << 1$ is a very useful approximation in mathematical physics and comes from the [binomial theorem](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/alg3.html).